# symfony 2 subdomains action setup

Tags: php, .htaccess, symfony

I have this full `routing` config files

```
#routing.yml
admin_hello:
    resource: "@WebsiteOnePageBundle/Resources/config/routing_admin.yml"
    host:     "manage.website.com"

website_one_page:
    resource: "@WebsiteOnePageBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
```

my problem is that if I `GET` or `POST` `manage.website.com/` the login action is triggered. if I GET or POST manage.website.com/users my usersAction is not triggered and I get 500 internal server error.

the official [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/routing/hostname_pattern.html) doesn't say anything about that.

the apache log says

```
Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer http://manage.website.com/
```

how can I avoid this internal redirections? or better... **how can I set up subdomains `URI` to be linked to its proper controller action?**

## UPDATE


even if I `GET` `manage.website.com/whatever` the same error appears...

other useful configurations info :

```
provider => godaddy
```

redirection folders for subdomains (I used the same folder for both the subdomains)

```
manage.website.com => /web
www.website.com => /web
```

googling about this error, I found that it's an `.htaccess` related problem. this is mine (`/web/.htaccess`)

```
# Use the front controller as index file. It serves as a fallback solution when
# every other rewrite/redirect fails (e.g. in an aliased environment without
# mod_rewrite). Additionally, this reduces the matching process for the
# start page (path "/") because otherwise Apache will apply the rewriting rules
# to each configured DirectoryIndex file (e.g. index.php, index.html, index.pl).
DirectoryIndex app.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Determine the RewriteBase automatically and set it as environment variable.
    # If you are using Apache aliases to do mass virtual hosting or installed the
    # project in a subdirectory, the base path will be prepended to allow proper
    # resolution of the app.php file and to redirect to the correct URI. It will
    # work in environments without path prefix as well, providing a safe, one-size
    # fits all solution. But as you do not need it in this case, you can comment
    # the following 2 lines to eliminate the overhead.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

    # Redirect to URI without front controller to prevent duplicate content
    # (with and without `/app.php`). Only do this redirect on the initial
    # rewrite by Apache and not on subsequent cycles. Otherwise we would get an
    # endless redirect loop (request -> rewrite to front controller ->
    # redirect -> request -> ...).
    # So in case you get a "too many redirects" error or you always get redirected
    # to the start page because your Apache does not expose the REDIRECT_STATUS
    # environment variable, you have 2 choices:
    # - disable this feature by commenting the following 2 lines or
    # - use Apache >= 2.3.9 and replace all L flags by END flags and remove the
    #   following RewriteCond (best solution)
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^app\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]

    # If the requested filename exists, simply serve it.
    # We only want to let Apache serve files and not directories.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule .? - [L]

    # Rewrite all other queries to the front controller.
    RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        # When mod_rewrite is not available, we instruct a temporary redirect of
        # the start page to the front controller explicitly so that the website
        # and the generated links can still be used.
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/
        # RedirectTemp cannot be used instead
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

tryed both to comment and uncomment the

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^app\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]
```

lines as the symfony "default" comments says

but still haven't found a solution

Comment: Something is overriding your routes, either a route previous to this or a firewall setting in your `security.yml`. Can you post your full `routing.yml` and `security.yml`? Remember that Symfony resolves to the first route it finds, therefore any routes that are found before your routes with the `host` parameter will be used first. That includes routes that don't use the `host` parameter since they apply to any host. This is a scenario where the Symfony profiler would be helpful as well (use the "view last 10" search)

Comment: even if I GET manage.website.com/asd the same error appears...

Comment: GoDaddy may very well be your problem... Is it a "subdomain redirect" **or** a subdomain alias? Can you replicate the problem if you test it on a local environment? Run a LAMP, WAMP, or MAMP stack on your computer, replicate your database, point it to your Symfony `/web` folder, and modify your hosts file to point `manage.website.com`, `seller.website.com`, and `www.website.com` to `127.0.0.1`

Comment: not aliases or redirects. seller and manage are A records in my DNS zone (host).

Comment: Hm... Something's fishy and I don't think your Symfony configuration is causing this problem...

Comment: I don't think it too (maybe a godaddy crazy behavior).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

adding these lines to my `.htaccess` solves the problem

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php?/$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: You should at least tell us where tou added those lines. That's quite important in an htaccess file.